hola, tengo un pequeño problema con el redireccionamiento de las rutas. podrian darme una mano
Aqui esta el codigo el cual no me redirecciona a mi formulario de registro, y cuando apreto para que vaya me lleva a error 404.
 1. "use client"; import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import Image from "next/image"; import { ColorRing } from
    "react-loader-spinner"; import textoLabels from
    "../data/wording.login.texto"; import { Button } from
    "@nextui-org/react"; import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
    
    
    
    const FormLogin = () => {   const router = useRouter();   const
    handleRegistrarseClick = () => {
        router.push('/registrarse');   };   return (
        <>
          <div
            className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center"
            style={{ backgroundImage: "url('/img/fondo.jpg')" }}
          >
            <div
              style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.76)" }}
              className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full max-w-lg rounded-lg shadow-lg p-8 m-10"
            >
              <div className="">
                <Image
                  className="w-202 h-202 mx-auto items-center   flex"
                  src="/img/logo.png"
                  alt="Logo"
                  width={200}
                  height={200}
                  priority
                />
              </div>
    
              <span className="block w-full text-xl text-center uppercase font-bold mb-4">
                Iniciar Sesión
              </span>
    
              <form className="w-full">
                <div className="mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="username" className="block text-xs mb-1">
                    {textoLabels.email}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="w-full border rounded-lg p-2 outline-none focus:shadow-outline bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 focus:bg-white"
                    type="email"
                    name="username"
                    id="username"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    autoComplete="username"
                  />
                </div>
        
                    <div className="mb-6">
                      <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-xs mb-1">
                        {textoLabels.password}
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="w-full border rounded-lg p-2 outline-none focus:shadow-outline bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50
    focus:bg-white"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <a className="text-white text-center text-sm mt-4 hover:text-yellow-400" href="/">
                      Olvidó su contraseña?
                    </a>
                    <div className="flex justify-center">
                      <button
                        className="bg-black hover:bg-yellow-400 hover:text-black hover:font-semibold text-white uppercase text-sm
    font-semibold px-4 py-2 rounded"
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        Login
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={handleRegistrarseClick}>
                        ¿Aún no te registraste?, hacelo aca
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        };
        
        export default FormLogin;


Estas seguro de que la ruta-segmento /registrarse existe en el directorio app? Comparte una imagen de como se ve tu working directory en especial el directorio app
